# How to prove that $\left\{\gamma \in \alpha^{+}: \beta + \gamma \leq \alpha\right\}$ is not a limit ordinal given that $\alpha \geq \beta$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am proving the following theorem and somewhat got stuck:

> Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are ordinals with $\alpha \geq \beta$. Let $X = \left\{\gamma \in \alpha^{+}: \beta + \gamma \leq \alpha\right\}$. Then $X$ is a successor ordinal.

I have proved that $X$ is an ordinal and that $X \neq \boldsymbol{0}$. But I am stuck at proving $X$ is not a limit ordinal. I tried to use transfinite induction on $\alpha$, but the process is very verbose, and I was stuck in the middle. Can anyone provide hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $X$ is (read: has the order type of) a successor ordinal is to show that $X$ has a maximum.

$X$ is a subset of $\alpha^+$, so $\gamma \le \alpha$ for all $\gamma \in X$, so $\sup\limits_{\gamma \in X} \gamma \le \alpha$, so $\sup\limits_{\gamma \in X} \gamma \in \alpha^+$.

Also, $\beta + \gamma \le \alpha$ for all $\gamma \in X$, so $\beta + \sup\limits_{\gamma \in X} \gamma = \sup\limits_{\gamma \in X} \,(\beta + \gamma) \le \alpha$.

Therefore, $\sup\limits_{\gamma \in X} \gamma \in X$, quod erat demonstrandum.

Comment: I guess what you mean by $\operatorname{sup}_{\gamma\in X}\gamma$ is the same as $\operatorname{lub}X$, right?

Comment: Yes.$ $$ $$ $$ $

Comment: Good thoughts. The only thing left is to show the existence of $\operatorname{lub}X$, which is straightforward, as $\operatorname{lub}X = \bigcup X$.